# Pivot table conversion generating value error in pands

Tags: python, pandas, cursor, pivot

I am fetching data from the table which contains

```
execution_time, type, status, process, sub_process, value 
2018-11-12 16:09:48.179547, backlog, started, p1, s1, 100
2018-11-12 16:09:48.179547, backlog, created, p1, s1, 1005
2018-11-12 16:09:48.179547, backlog, started, p2, s1, 500
2018-11-12 16:09:48.179547, V1, created, p1, s1, 10
2018-11-12 16:09:48.179547, V2, created, p1, s1, 15
2018-11-12 16:09:48.179547, backlog, started, p3, s1, 0
2018-11-12 16:09:48.179547, backlog, started, p4, s1, 45
2018-11-12 16:09:48.179547, V1, started, p4, s1, 400
```

I want to pivot this data such that it should be like this:

status, process, sub_process, backlog, V1, V2

(backlog, V1 and V2 should contain corresponding values if exists)
Here is my code. I am getting error as

> pivot_table() got multiple values for argument 'values'

```
sql = "select * from temp.data_table"
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df=df.pivot_table(index=['status','process','sub_process'],columns='type',values='value', aggfunc = 'sum')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using (remove `df` in `pivot_table` )

```
df.pivot_table(index=['status','process','sub_process'],columns='type',values='value', aggfunc = 'sum')
Out[85]: 
type                             V1    V2   backlog
status   process sub_process                       
 created  p1      s1           10.0  15.0    1005.0
 started  p1      s1            NaN   NaN     100.0
          p2      s1            NaN   NaN     500.0
          p3      s1            NaN   NaN       0.0
          p4      s1          400.0   NaN      45.0
```

Or `pd.pivot_table`

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['status','process','sub_process'],columns='type',values=['value'], aggfunc = 'sum')
Out[86]: 
                              value               
type                             V1    V2  backlog
status   process sub_process                      
 created  p1      s1           10.0  15.0   1005.0
 started  p1      s1            NaN   NaN    100.0
          p2      s1            NaN   NaN    500.0
          p3      s1            NaN   NaN      0.0
          p4      s1          400.0   NaN     45.0
```

Comment: hey @W-B I removed df  but I am getting error as "KeyError: 'value'"

Comment: @MadhuraMhatre check you df columns by df.columns , i think you have white space there

Comment: This is what my revised line looks like df=df.pivot_table(index=['status','process','sub_process'],columns='type',values='value',aggfunc ='sum')

Comment: Thats interesting I still get that "KeyError: 'value'"